# Unable to print json value to a integer array list? is saves there but unable to take out off the loop?

Tags: java, android, json

Can anybody help me to take the `arraylist` out of the loop. If I take it out, it's coming empty as array out of bound. Here is my code:

```
public void collapse() {
    corequestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    String url="http://192.168.43.208/online/json.php";
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest3=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray=response.getJSONArray("server_responce");
                    for (int i=0;i<=jsonArray.length();i++){

                        JSONObject admin=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        solution.add(Integer.valueOf(admin.getString("sno")));

                    //if i do like this the values prints here in the toast.        
                    //Toast.makeText(User_Login.this, "hello"+solution.get(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //printing the toast anywhere out of the block gives error.. as assay out of bound 0 on index size 0.. help me guys
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Volly","error");
            }
        }

        );
    corequestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest3);
    Toast.makeText(User_Login.this, "hello"+solution.get(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The last line gives me error I can't take the array list anywhere outside because it's coming out empty. It's perfect when it is inside the loop and values are adding to it. I have checked it, only thing is I cant take it out?

Comment: Post where u have declared solution list?

Comment: please post that you are supposed to receive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

volley respoce will give the detail only aftercertain time bz of internet.so i have used handler.. to call the meathod which i should execute.here is it.

```
     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(User_Login.this, ""+solution.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Collections.shuffle(solution);
            data();
        }
    },i*3000);
```

my code to add json to array list: i can set if condition for checking arraylist size to know where there is proper internet or not..

```
            try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray=response.getJSONArray("server_responce");
                        for (int i=0;i<=jsonArray.length();i++){

                            JSONObject admin=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String bno = admin.getString("bno");
                            String series=admin.getString("sno");
                            if (bnum.equals(bno)) {
                                int k = Integer.valueOf(series);
                                solution.add(k);
                            }

                        }
```

Comment: U shud not use Handler's here @Bathri .this may cause performance issues..

Comment: Its not after sometime its in thread it'll take time not because of internet its thread functionality. If u think handler is better solution how much time will u set if u have huge data to parse in that thread?

Comment: I have used @RushiAyyappa suggestions to form my answer. Can u check?

Comment: this is just a small program bro.. so i have used this way.i have to set a statement to get full json detail.and proceed. to the next step thats it... provide me any other solution .. if u have guys @RushiAyyappa... to get and store json to my arraylist

Answer (score 0):

Expecting that you have given your ArrayList of type of Integer globally.

```
public void collapse(){
solution = new ArrayList<>();
corequestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
String url="http://192.168.43.208/online/json.php";
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest3=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray=response.getJSONArray("server_responce");
                for (int i=0;i<=jsonArray.length();i++){

                    JSONObject admin=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String val=admin.optString("sno"));
                    if(!val.equalIgnoreCase(""))
                    solution.add(Integer.parseInt(val);

                    //if i do like this the values prints here in the toast.        

                    //printing the toast anywhere out of the block gives error.. as assay out of bound 0 on index size 0.. help me guys
                }
    Toast.makeText(User_Login.this, "hello"+solution.get(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              if(solution.size()!=0)
               { 
               Collections.shuffle(solution) 
               }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Volly","error");
        }
    }
);
corequestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest3);

}
```

Comment: Can u elaborate ur answer please?

Comment: Author's code is giving an exception while converting the received code form String to integer hence the arraylist is empty. My code will solve this issue.

Comment: This solution will not work. as JsonObjectRequest is asynchronous call so it will surely throw exception  `array out of bound 0 on index size 0` when you try to  get `solution.get(0)`

Comment: @RushiAyyappa can u see the Toast _Author_ commented "Toast.makeText(User_Login.this, "hello"+solution.get(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //printing the toast anywhere out of the block gives error" in the onResponse block. If he get the class cast exception he would have get the error there itself right?

Comment: yes.u r correct.one min i will edit my answer.Thanks @Raghavendra

Comment: did this help you?

Comment: @RushiAyyappa there is no changes in the code . same error occur... the last tost msg creates error ...java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0.... help me guys

Comment: i have removed the toast at the bottom.did you see?

Comment: @BathriNathan I am not aware of the flow of Volley. If its in thread then u can't directly get the value before it finishes the parsing.

Comment: @Raghavendra the code i have written can you check once? I feel i have written good enough.

Comment: @BathriNathan Ofcourse I need to read the doc but will u double check can u directly access that array list in the very next statement after adding it to queue

Comment: toast in the for loops give no error.. but i need to save those sno in array list and and take it out ...can u give me a way..@RushiAyyappa

Comment: @RushiAyyappa As I see the _Author_ wants arraylist outside the parsing u didn't show him how to get that edit your answer:)

Comment: Since you cannot use the arraylist once all the parsing is finished.You have to write all the operations inside onResponse () method after parsing in try block.Now i have removed toast in for loop and added it after the loop.if you are pssing this value to any other activity or adapter write it's relative code in the place i have written the Toast.

Comment: yes excately ... i am trying it for several hrs... help me out with a concept guys....

Comment: @BathriNathan what do u want to do with the arraylist after JSON parsing in the response method?

Comment: wana  Collections.shuffle(solution); and create random sno... sooo i wana bring it out...did u find a way gentle men...?

Comment: @BathriNathan now Rushi Ayyappa's soln. looks to be work put your statements where Toast is there and try

Comment: copy paste my code exactly and check it now.i have added your requirement below Toast.

Comment: sry bros u did  not get my error i think so... everthing is working inside the for loop and try brock...but when ever bring the array list outside the set of block eroor occurs@RushiAyyappa

Comment: not able to use in the same meathod itself...      );
        corequestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest3);
        Toast.makeText(User_Login.this, "hello"+solution.get(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); why i cant use it outside....

    }

Comment: yes obviuosly,you cannot bring the arraylist outside the try block filled with data. Outside try block your arraylist is empty.in other ways, onResponse get called after everything else in your activity got executed.

Comment: corequestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest3); you cannot write anything under this.because whatever you write under this statement that gets executed before onResponse is called.

Comment: so no other way to get it out ... or to store json values??? @RushiAyyappa

Comment: @BathriNathan Let me try one soln. Create a method which accepts arraylist and do ur stuff there, what u want to do with that arraylist and in the onResposne call that method by passing that list after the loop. No need to global declaration make it local only

Comment: Dear @BathriNathan as i said.once parsing is done..it means from the place i have written the Toast statement. you can do anything you want.coz once all the other methods gets executed onResponse shows up and whatever you have written after parsing catches up and continue to execute.so if you want to move this value to another activity .instead of toast write startActivty() ..remove toast

Comment: @Raghavendra do you see someone gave a downvote? how can someone do this without even try to resolve?

Comment: @BathriNathan I can post a soln. Please post what r u trying to do, in your way _out off the loop_

Comment: thank u guys... for helping me... i will make a solution and inform uuu alll thxx a lott... :)

Comment: okay.but surely psot the answer.we are excited to know the hideout!

Comment: @Raghavendra yes it surely does.Coz i implement same way since i have started doing android..I don't think there is something else other than this.Let's see.

Comment: check my ans guys... its is a simple solution work for me fine... in anyway@RushiAyyappa  and @raghavendra